# I can not require any third lib in CloudCode, I have 'npm install --save ' the dependency in parse-server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

For example: I want to use lib 'ldapjs' in cloudCode.

1st: i run cmd `'npm install --save ldapjs'` in parse-server

2nd: i checked the package.json  `"ldapjs": "^1.0.2"`

3rd: i require it in my cloud code.   const ldap = require('ldapjs');

```
const ladp = require('ladpjs')
Parse.Cloud.define("sendMail", (request, response) => {
  console.log('test......send email')  
});
```

At last, i run parse-server, error occurs: "Error: Cannot find module 'ladpjs'"

I am confused, as many answers told me this would work... But it has no work in my environment.

I can not use any 3rd lib, such as mailgun.

Answer (score 0):

well, i maybe know why.
I git clone the source code and run by lib/cli/parse-server.js directly. Besides i add dependency lib into the parse-server’s package.json。With this way, i can not require lib in the cloud code.
But, i download the parse-server-example, then add dependency to the package.json, then reuqire the lib in the cloud code, it works...Ohh